# Reverse engineer toBinaryString and toHexString

Tags: java

I am to write a program to convert input from Octal into Binary or Hex however I cannot use the pre-written API Routines to do the conversions for me. I figure my best bet is to reverse engineer them and see how it is they function. Does anyone know of a source that could  give that information, or other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: How about the source code itself?

Comment: Forgive me, but I am new and don't know where to find the source code.

Comment: Java is open source. You can see source code of all it methods.

Comment: @user2877099. It's on your machine. Comes bundled with JDK. Look out for `src.zip` directory. Or if that doesn't help, Google is always there.

Comment: Don't reverse engineer. Think your way through! You're learning how to program. This is: learning how to _solve problems with code_. Not: _find code that already solves it_. That's like an architect that know how to build an Eiffel Tower. It's not useful anymore

Comment: Yes, this is not a hard problem, and once you've solved it for one base it's easy to extrapolate to others.  Don't be content to just copy code from somewhere, but figure out how to do it.  (Hint: Modulo arithmetic -- using the `%` operator -- is a big part of it.)

Comment: If you can't use the pre-written API routines it is asinine to think that you can just lift their source code. You're supposed to learn something out of this exercise, not just plagiarize an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download intelliJ, then you can control click into any class.

Also, just try googling "source code for java lang Integer"

I did and it brought up:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java

This is basically how you would do it with the JDK (as someone pointed out):

```
    String octalNo="037";
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(octalNo, 8)));
```

For fun, I did the octal problem:

```
    int octal = 037;

    System.out.println(octalToHexString(octal));

    int octal = 037;

    System.out.println(octalToHexString(octal));

}

public static String octalToHexString(int octal) {

    final  char[] hex = {
            '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
            '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'A' , 'B' ,
            'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'F'
    };


    int val = octal;
    int radix = 0;
    int mask = 0;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("0x");

    if (val==0) {
        return "0x" + 0;
    }

    while (val != 0) {

        radix = 1 << 4;
        mask = radix - 1;
        builder.insert(2, hex[val & mask]);
        val >>>= 4;
    }

    return builder.toString();

}
```

The above is not very efficient. :)

Here is the parser from the JDK for int:

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
            throws NumberFormatException
{
    /*
     * WARNING: This method may be invoked early during VM initialization
     * before IntegerCache is initialized. Care must be taken to not use
     * the valueOf method.
     */

    if (s == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    }

    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                                        " less than Character.MIN_RADIX");
    }

    if (radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                                        " greater than Character.MAX_RADIX");
    }

    int result = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 0, len = s.length();
    int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int multmin;
    int digit;

    if (len > 0) {
        char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
        if (firstChar < '0') { // Possible leading "+" or "-"
            if (firstChar == '-') {
                negative = true;
                limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            } else if (firstChar != '+')
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);

            if (len == 1) // Cannot have lone "+" or "-"
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            i++;
        }
        multmin = limit / radix;
        while (i < len) {
            // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            if (digit < 0) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            if (result < multmin) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result *= radix;
            if (result < limit + digit) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result -= digit;
        }
    } else {
        throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
    }
    return negative ? result : -result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the basics, that is to convert decimal numbers to binary. The process is quite easy. Then, you can move on to what you stated cause the process is similar.

As others have already pointed out, the source code comes bundled with the jdk.